# Extracting a time interval from NetCDF-data in ArcMap Desktop 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, spatial-analysis, weighted-overlay, opendap

In ArcMap 10.4 (advanced licence) I have added a netcdf-file with EU-temperature-over-time data (time being every day between 1995 to 2016).

I just need the year 2010 from this data, but I'm still struggling to extract this year. I'm new to python, and the only code I found to extract timeslices was accessing a band to extract the slice. It's from the esri support: http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011318 . 
But I can't manage to make a band from the time dimension of my netcdf-file, ArcGIS always crashes somewhere along the way.

I also tried by OPeNDAP-access to get just this one year of data, both downloading it directly from the website as dods, and trying to access the url, directly through the ArcMap tool (make OpENDAP-layer). The download page ( http://opendap.knmi.nl/knmi/thredds/dodsC/e-obs_0.25regular/tn_0.25deg_reg_v15.0.nc.html ) provides the url in a specific slot. But the tool could not connect with the URL, it gives the "error 000241: The specified pathname or file type is invalid for the required input". And I did not find a way to open .dods with ArcMap.

Does anyone know a simple code-snippet I could have a go at editing as a beginner? Or is there a way directly in ArcMap to extract parts of the file? Ore does anyone have a solution to my OPeNDAP-Problems?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, GIS SE isn't really organized to give extensive advice on a broad range of data management issues and potential problems.  Unlike in discussion forums, we're more focused on addressing a single, specific problem.  I would suggest that even in discussion forums, and particularly here, that you specify the exact software you are using (both in name and by version) early in the problem statement, so that folks who are not able to help with that software not be forced to read the entire question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Vince, I hope it's better now. Extremely sorry to be not very specific, hopefully somebody can at least outline a path to horizon...

Comment: If you "struggle even with extracting a year from the netcdf data" then I think that is what you should focus this question on.  Everything else can be asked about in separate questions later, that is if the answers to the first focussed question does not resolve all your issues.